Animating an ellipse only while mouse is over grid
I have am writing a xaml project with an ellipse drawn inside a grid. Currently, I am animating the length and width of the ellipse repeatedly once the grid is loaded. I want to make the following changes:
I want the animation to begin and repeat itself while the mouse is over the grid. When the mouse leaves the grid, I want the animation to complete its current cycle and then stop when finished.
Here is the repeat-forever version of my code:
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Woo_Loo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Main Window" Height="115" Width="115" Background="Transparent" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName="Elips" TargetProperty="Width">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="100" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25"
                            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <SineEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName="Elips" TargetProperty="Height">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:0.25"
                            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <SineEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
        <Ellipse Name="Elips" StrokeThickness="10" Stroke="Red" Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="0" />
    </Grid>
</Window>


I'm not sure whether to use event triggers to modify the repeatbehavior properties, or somehow use a mouseover property to change the repeatbehavior property, or letting the repeatbehavior to be conditional, or what. I'm a beginner at xaml. I want to avoid using code-behind if possible.

How to: Trigger an Animation When a Property Value Changes

Changing the start of the animation is not difficult.
You just need to replace the Loaded launch event with MouseEnter.
But stopping will be more difficult. The event when the cursor leaves the grid is MouseLeave. In XAML, you can stop the animation immediately. But you need to wait for the current loop to complete. I think you can’t do without Sharp code in this case.
